# Kibana 5.4.0 - Vertical Bar Data Visualization Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am able to create index and in discovery tab all the data is being populated shown properly.

```
   {
  "_index": "deal-expense",
  "_type": "kafka-connect",
  "_id": "deal-expense+0+63",
  "_version": 2,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "EXPENSE_CODE": "NL**20",
    "EXPENSE_CODE_DESCRIPTION": "DO NOT USE ****** ****** - ADAM",
    "NO_OF_DEALS": 17
  }
}
```

Data Visualization Requirement:

1. There might be multiple indexed documents for every `EXPENSE_CODE`
2. On Y Axis I need to display Max Of `NO_OF_DEALS` and On X Axis I need to display `EXPENSE_CODE`
3. Max Of `NO_OF_DEALS` are not being populated but `EXPENSE_CODE` is being populated.

My Configurations as shown below. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create the elastic search index and map it to existing index mentioned in the question.

```
PUT /reindexed-deal-expense
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "EXPENSE_CODE": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "NO_OF_DEALS": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and map it like this

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "deal-expense"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "reindexed-deal-expense"
  }
}
```

[image]